# How to grep the part of the line after the second pattern

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Eg:

```
set_false_path -from [sdhjasdjhfvsdhf] -through [fsdfvhbdf] -through [sakjvhbdskfhvbdf jbhshbv sdjkvb]
```

I want to grep the line from the second through only.

Comment: Is there anything you tried so far ? Please share your research. Also share the context of your question to make sure that it is not an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

```
Expression='set_false_path -from [sdhjasdjhfvsdhf] -through [fsdfvhbdf] -through [sakjvhbdskfhvbdf jbhshbv sdjkvb]'

printf '%s' "$Expression" | grep -o -e '-through \[[^]]*\]' | sed -ne '2p'
```

Output:

```
-through [sakjvhbdskfhvbdf jbhshbv sdjkvb]
```

Comment: invalid command name "^"

Comment: Did you copy/paste the two commands?

Comment: first  i used 'set' to provide data to Expression then i copy/pasted the second command

Comment: "set"?  Isn't that a csh command?  You tagged your question with "bash", so I assumed Bourne Shell syntax would do.  What is your current shell, or the shell indicated in the shebang line, in case you're running this in a script?

Comment: yeah im using csh commands

Comment: So, at least you could edit your post and replace "bash" with "csh".
Also, I copied/pasted those two commands in a csh session and was unable to reproduce the error you reported.